# Bone Layers in Edit Mode are Different Than in Pose Mode

Tags: armature, bones, layers

I can't figure out why this model won't show all of the bones in pose mode. I think it has to do with the bone layers, but I don't know how to move them. Even with all of the layers selected, only some of the bones appear.

This image shows what pose mode looks like:

[image: Bones Visible In Pose Mode]

And this is what edit mode looks like:

[image: Bones Visible in Edit Mode]

No bones are hidden. Alt-H does nothing. The problem may also be related to bone groups.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it looks like your bones have custom shapes, if you go in Pose mode, select a bone, go in the Properties panel > Bone > Display > Custom Shape, some meshes are used to display the bone in another way than a classic octahedral shape. Is it what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the cause of my problems. Is there a way to delete all custom shapes? I'd rather not do it manually. There's a lot of bones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your bones have custom shapes, if you go in *Pose* mode, select a bone, go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Display* > *Custom Shape*, some meshes are used to display the bone in another way than a classic octahedral shape. Press on the little X to delete. I don't think you can delete them all at the same time.

[image]